# php echo is not working

Tags: php, mysql, forms, echo

my code doesnt seem to work.. the radio buttons appear but nothing beside them .. it seems as if the mysql_fetch_array is not working for some reason as i have played about with the code and repeatedly tested it to find where the code seems to encounter a problem and stop working.. could someone please advise what is wrong? cheers ps. i am new at this, only finished learning the php tutorial on w3schools last few days.

```
<body>

<?php

include 'dbyear2.php';

          $qnumber = $_REQUEST['uqn']; // obtain question number from URL

         $find = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Renal WHERE UQN='$qnumber'");

              while($retrieve=mysql_fetch_array($find));
        {

$retrieve['question'] = $question;
$retrieve['MCQ_A'] = $a;
$retrieve['MCQ_B'] = $b;
$retrieve['MCQ_C'] = $c;
$retrieve['MCQ_D'] = $d;
$retrieve['MCQ_E'] = $e;
$retrieve['answer'] = $answer;
$retrieve['MCQ_correct'] = $correct;


   }




  ?>


             <form action='check.php' method='POST'>  

         <table> 

<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr><td><input type='radio' name='group1' value='A' /></td><td> <?php echo $a; ?></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type='radio' name='group1' value='B' /></td><td> <?php echo $b; ?></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type='radio' name='group1' value='C' /></td><td> <?php echo $c; ?></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type='radio' name='group1' value='D' /></td><td> <?php echo $d; ?></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type='radio' name='group1' value='E' /></td><td> <?php echo $e; ?></td></tr> 
<tr>

<?php 

// sending the retrieved information from MYSQL via POST for use in check.php file

$qnumber;
$a;
    $b;
   $c;
      $d;
     $e;
      $answer;
 $correct;


  ?></tr>
       <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td></tr>





     </table>

        </form>




      </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 6):

This part is backwards:

```
$retrieve['question'] = $question;
$retrieve['MCQ_A'] = $a;
$retrieve['MCQ_B'] = $b;
$retrieve['MCQ_C'] = $c;
$retrieve['MCQ_D'] = $d;
$retrieve['MCQ_E'] = $e;
$retrieve['answer'] = $answer;
$retrieve['MCQ_correct'] = $correct;
```

Should be

```
$question = $retrieve['question' ;
$a = $retrieve['MCQ_A'];
$b = $retrieve['MCQ_B'];
$c = $retrieve['MCQ_C'];
$d = $retrieve['MCQ_D'];
$e = $retrieve['MCQ_E'];
$answer = $retrieve['answer'];
$correct $retrieve['MCQ_correct'];
```

[Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

**You are also wide open to [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174)**

You should not use [w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com). It's not a reliable source of information and we don't want to encourage its use.

Comment: +1 to the w3schools comment. It's amazing how many people still use their tutorials. They teach everything that's wrong about programming.

Comment: absolutely everything </sarcasm>

Comment: also +1 for the w3schools comment, mysql_ comment, and injection comment!

Comment: oh wow, i didnt know the = operator functions in only one direction. i have amended my code as per however it still doesnt work.

also, thank you very much for informing me that the mysql API is going to be deprecated - this has saved me alot of future work. However, i am not sure whether i should start using PDO or MySQLi. i read teh article you linked however i dont understand all teh features. MySQLi seems to include everything apart from "API supports client-side Prepared Statements" and im not sure what this means or if i will need this.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong direction when assigning. Use this:

```
$e = $retrieve['MCQ_E'];
```

Comment: i have changed this however it is still not working. any other suggestions?